# Could "Give in" mean "Hand over"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, differences, synonyms, phrasal-verbs

Give in = hand in but does give in = hand over? and which of them are equal? and what's the differences?

Answer (score 3):

"give in" does not = "hand in"
nor does "give in" = "hand over"

- HAND IN is what students would do with a completed assignment. Suppose the teacher "handed out" question sheets to all the students. Then when they had filled in answers, they would "hand in" the completed sheets to the teacher. She first spread them "out" (to students), then gathered them "in" (to herself).
- HAND OVER is what you would do if a robber confronted you:  "Hand over all your money or I'll shoot!"  However, it need not be violent; you could choose to "hand over" a task to someone. So it means giving something that you own, to someone else, willingly or unwillingly.
- if you already started a task, you might say you were HANDING {IT} OFF to someone—like a relay runner passing a baton to the next runner. (This act is called a "handoff") .
- GIVE IN is an idiom for letting the other person have his way.
- If you have been fighting (physically or verbally), then quit fighting and surrender, you are GIVING UP. (This is intransitive as well as transitive; you can "give up the fight" or just "give up".) However, you can also voluntarily give something up, such as giving up your place in line, or giving up your seat on a bus, to an elderly or handicapped person. But if you "give up the ghost" it means you died!

So, if someone persuades you to give them something of yours, you might "give in" and "hand it over".  If he tries to wrestle you to take it away, and he's standing over you with his boot on your neck, you might "give up" and "hand it over".

If you are an escaped murderer, and the police surround your house, they might shout "GIVE UP and come out with your HANDS UP!"

And then there are "hands off", "hands down", "hand-me-downs" "off-hand", and more. But those are other questions; I've gone on long enogh here.

Comment: thanks but does give in for example if you are ill and in a hospital but there's not enough places so someone give in his bed for you doesn't give in in this situation mean hand over
moreover this dictionary says that give in = hand in http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/give+in?r=66

Comment: No, in that situation, the person is GIVING UP his bed for you, not GIVING IN his bed for you. Give up is to relinquish possession, while give in is to yield way, or to submit, or stop opposing. Give in does not mean to give possession of a thing. Give in means to give control to a person or force.

Comment: The dictionary link the OP cited provides definitions for "give".  These are not definitions for "give in", although that is the search term you searched for. I can see how this might be confusing, as it did find EXAMPLES for "give in".